# Sidebar graphics distort when pulled

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, ios-app

When you pull the sidebar on the Stack Exchange app to the right, after a certain limit it begins to distort and stretch.

[image: stretchy-appy-thingy-image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

It's always struck me as mildly annoying, but I never looked into it.  It's a [feature of the library](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController/blob/08b153860e26ddbe6b8906909fb30e32c670a9f4/MMDrawerController/MMDrawerController.h#L162).